# div with specific class wont center

Tags: html, css

this is what the class im talking about is in CSS:

```
.border {
    width: 400px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #fef9bb;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 15px;
}
```

Divs with that certain class wont center, even when I do this:
CSS

```
centre {
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<centre>
<div class="border">
<p>placeholder</p>
</div>
</centre>
```

But, it only centers the elements inside the div, and not the div itself.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It seems like you want this, right?

```css
.border {
  width: 400px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fef9bb;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 15px;
}

centre {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<centre>
  <div class="border">
    <p>placeholder</p>
  </div>
</centre>
```

Comment: That does work, but I've came across another problem, it makes elements go into a line, like this. [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/k52jR0k) (for some reason imgur thinks it has "18+" content)

Comment: @Francis You can add `flex-direction: column;` to `centre` to make them go into many lines